# Affine transform of non rectangular part of the image

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, affinetransform

I'm trying to create app for applying Affine transform only for some part of image(non rectangular).

http://s29.postimg.org/k45fwbmsn/Untitled.png

Is there exist any way, to transform only selected(visible) part of the image?

Comment: What do you mean by transparent? Are you just trying to cut out the black rectangle and transform it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm certain the overall transformation you described (only on part of an image) is not affine. So it isn't as easy as applying a matrix multiplication to some vectors.

But of course, there are ways to define algorithms that detect black rectangles and apply an affine transformation to the coordinates of detected rectangles. With the transformed coordinates you can draw a new quadrangle. Note: After an affine transformation it does not need to be a rectangle anymore.

Btw. you're contradicting yourself:

> transform only for some part of image(**non rectangular**).

vs

> to transform **only black rectangle**

I'd propose you clarify the following points about your input and expected output:

- Which of the contradicting transformations do you want: Only rectangles or everything but rectangles?
- Is it binary black-and-white, gray-level or colour image? This is a question of simple to complex input with quite some impact on the algorithm.
- Is the image noiseless, i.e. is it true black or all sorts of really dark colours? For true black you might be able to apply a simple heuristic to detect the rectangles. If it's a noisy image you need to think about image filters/improvements and colour space transitions.
- Are the rectangles the only "black" areas in your image?
- Are the rectangles in parallel to x and y axis? Again this is simple heuristic vs pattern recognition.
- Is the number of rectangles known? Are multiple rectangles related (in size, proportions, parallel) to each other?
- What is to happen on borders or with image parts revealed by moving/shrinking the rectangles?

I'll edit the answer, when you provide the required information in your question.